# Ranking function does not work correct in the final part. How do i make it complete towards 100%?

Tags: php

On my text based game I have a ranking function called getRank, this allowes the user to get the specified rank according to the points they have acclaimed.
Yet when the last one is achieved, it sticks at 0%, where it should go towards 100% of the final rank.

I tried to lenghten the points that would be within the last rank from 7501 to 10.000 making it check if it is between 7501 and 10.000 etc, instead of topping it of on 7500, but that does not seem to do the trick.

What am I doing wrong in here?

**CODE:**

```
<?php

function getRank($punten)
{  
    if($punten >= 0 && $punten <= 350){
        $rank = array(1, 0, 350);  
    }

    elseif($punten >= 351 && $punten <= 750){
        $rank = array(2, 351, 750);
     }
    elseif($punten >= 751 && $punten <= 1200){       
        $rank = array(3, 751, 1200);
    }    
    elseif($punten >= 1201 && $punten <= 1750){
        $rank = array(4, 1201, 1750);
    }   
    elseif($punten >= 1751 && $punten <= 2400){
        $rank = array(5, 1751, 2400);
    }   
    elseif($punten >= 2401 && $punten <= 3200){      
        $rank = array(6, 2401, 3200);
    }    
    elseif($punten >= 3201 && $punten <= 4200){
        $rank = array(7, 3201, 4200); 
    }  
    elseif($punten >= 4201 && $punten <= 5600){
        $rank = array(8, 4201, 5600); 
    }
    elseif($punten >= 5601 && $punten <= 7500){
        $rank = array(9, 5601, 7500); 
    }  
    elseif($punten > 7500){
        $rank = array(10);
    }      
    if(!isset($rank)){
        return array(1, 0); 
    }       
    if($rank[0] == 10){
        $vordering = 0;
    } 
    else{        
        $vordering = floor((($punten - $rank[1]) / (($rank[2] - $rank[1]) + 1)) * 100);     
        return array($rank[0], $vordering);
    }
    $tmpRank = getRank($data->ervaringspunten);$oudeRank = $data->rank;$data->rank = $tmpRank[0];$data->rankvord = $tmpRank[1];
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to format your code so we can read it?

Comment: I think i did it now? It was my first post here, so i had to find out how that would go. :)

Comment: I understand the difficulty. Your code is currently on 2 lines, is that really how you've written it? It is normal in coding to keep lines relatively short, say no longer than 120 characters. See [psr-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#23-lines). For instance, you could start a new line after each semi-colon, that's a `';'`, that would easily do it. Better formatted code is easier to read and to debug.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will keep that noted from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's a lot better to read. I completely rewrote your code because it is still very difficult to follow what it does. Humans have real trouble understanding code with many `if ... elseif ... elseif .... else .... if .... else` in them. Bugs easily slip in that way.

My basic idea is that you probably intend something like this:

```
function getRank($points)
{
    $limits = [350, 750, 1200, 1750, 2400, 3200, 4200, 5600, 7500, 10000];
    $previousLimit = 0;
    foreach ($limits as $rank => $limit) {
        if ($limit >= $points) {
          $percentage = floor((($points - $previousLimit) / 
                              (($limit - $previousLimit))) * 100);  
          return [$rank, $percentage];
        }
        $previousLimit = $limit;
    }
    return "error";
}

print_r(getRank(1550));
```

This returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 63 )
```

Note that I use one language when I program, even though I am Dutch, so reading your `$punten` is not a problem for me. Sticking to English keeps it consistent, and also readable for people who do not understand Dutch (that is: most programmers). I didn't worry about an upper limit. So something like:

```
print_r(getRank(15550));
```

will therefore return:

```
error
```

You can easily replace that with anything you want.

Creating good code takes practice, but bad code always get certain things wrong: 1. lots of repetition. 2. difficult to read. 3. complex execution flow. Try to avoid those.

Another useful link: https://phptherightway.com

Comment: It does look a lot cleaner, thank you for that. I will keep it in mind to keep the variables also in English, to make it more easy to convert in case of problems. 

However it did not do the trick either. It keeps sticking towards the 0% once it reaches the final level. Basically i am trying to get the final level at 100% with a certain amount of points, just as the other ranks.

Comment: @Alcapone1993: I tested the code and I don't find that it keeps sticking towards the 0% once it reaches the final level: At 8550 it returns rank 9 at 42%, and anything above 10000 will return `error`, as is written in the code. If you want a percentage above 10000 you will have to say _in respect to what_ it should be.

Comment: I did try that code part you gave me. And it did look cleaner, so i addapted the input style towards the now re-written part. Unfortunately i overlooked another part of the script, that guided the point system also. So it did not work in the first instance. I changed a few things of the other script and it started working after that was removed. 

Your connection was a lot shorter and cleaner, so i have chosen that solution. Thanks for the help.